# How To Turn Off Caching in some page in website?

Tags: codeigniter, caching, versioning

I have pages that change assets every day from glorious images on sliders and so on. I have the idea to turn off caching only on that page. How do you do this in Codeigniter framework?

I've tried versioning on a css file but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can **trick the browser** by adding random numbers at the end of the file import.

As the number is almost never the same, the **browser will always think it is a different file**. (There's a small chance that the number will repeat, but it's fine)

[Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=pt-br) you can learn more about browser caching.

I guess that your code is PHP, so do the following on [file imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css?rnd=<?php echo (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax(); ?>">
```

You can do that if your file extension is **.php**